# unable to access authentication in openshift installed on prem though command line access works fine

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress

I have installed this openshift cluster on-prem.
I am able to access the cluster using the command line.
But I am not able to access the UI using this url:
https://console-openshift-console.apps.myapp-name.com/

The url redirects to the authentication process:

https://oauth-openshift.apps.myapp-name.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=console&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole-openshift-console.apps.sasi-molsheim.biocontinuum-innovation.com%2Fauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=user%3Afull&state=7f7c3188

However the authentication page does not display. I get the following message:

Application is not available

The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.

Possible reasons you are seeing this page:

```
The host doesn't exist. Make sure the hostname was typed correctly and that a route matching this hostname exists.
The host exists, but doesn't have a matching path. Check if the URL path was typed correctly and that the route was created using the desired path.
Route and path matches, but all pods are down. Make sure that the resources exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have at least one pod running.
```

What should I be looking at to try to solve this problem?

I have looked at the

Authentication operator
the pods of the authentication operator
At the logs of the pods
At the certificate being used by the authentication operator

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-2-108-133 ~]$ oc project openshift-authentication
Now using project "openshift-authentication" on server "https://api.my-app-name.com:6443".
[ec2-user@ip-10-2-108-133 ~]$ oc get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
oauth-openshift-588669875c-8k6gh   1/1     Running   0          30d
oauth-openshift-588669875c-jqtfx   1/1     Running   0          30d
oauth-openshift-588669875c-m4hgp   1/1     Running   0          30d
[ec2-user@ip-10-2-108-133 ~]$ oc get svc
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
oauth-openshift   ClusterIP   172.30.195.31   <none>        443/TCP   54d
[ec2-user@ip-10-2-108-133 ~]$
```

But nothing is apparent. What might be causing the problem? And how to solve it? I am ready to display more logs and commands output if anyone would like to help here.

I have looked at the

Authentication operator
the pods of the authentication operator
At the logs of the pods
At the certificate being used by the authentication operator

But nothing is apparent. What might be causing the problem? And how to solve it? I am ready to display more logs and commands output if anyone would like to help here.

Comment: I just wonder if you could solve FQDN name `oauth-openshift.apps.myapp-name.com` on the server which the oc command is executed?

And `oc get co` shows the status of cluster operators like if the cluster works well or not.

Comment: Please were you able to find a solution ? i have the same issue...if yes, can you share with us ? thanks